# Pycharm doesnt debug the cells

Tags: debugging, pycharm

I am new to the pycharm, and I don't know how to debug the cells from the menus. so I found the shortcut for this
[image]
but it doesn't work. how not working shortcut can be diagnosed. also answer what are alternatives ways to debug a cell(guessing probably from the menu, which by the way I can't find where is `debug cell`)?

note by hitting `shift` twice, there is a general command bar, and this `debug cell` can be found there but still not working.